# Open a Url via jQuery Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I found some codes and sources code from google.com.

I made function in Javascript.

```
        function a(URL, COORDS, ALT, LINK) {
        document.write('<AREA SHAPE="poly" ');
        document.write('id="'+URL+'" href="http://www.domain.com/' + URL);
        /*This line where you configure the output URL, put your domain name address here */

        document.writeln('" COORDS="' + COORDS + '" title="' + ALT + '" class="' + LINK + '">')
    }
```

It shows in HTML format (area tag with url link).

```
<area shape="poly" id="alberta.html" href="http://www.domain.com/alberta.html" coords="114,43" title="" class="">
```

I want that someone click that link, Open by jquery Popup same window.

I found it Simple Ajax > http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#examples

Thanks in Advance.